# Explanation required for WebDriver object mapping using Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

While creating WebDriver object we use, for example

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Why it cannot be as below,

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();
```

Just wanted to know the reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

**WebDriver** is an `interface`, we can not create `an instance` of it.

where as **ChromeDriver** is a class which extends `RemoteWebDriver` class.

and **RemoteWebDriver** class basically implements **WebDriver** `Interface`.

so writing  `new WebDriver();` is not valid in Java, since we can not create object of Interface. This will result in compile time error.

**Internal Implementation of WebDriver Interface :**

```
public interface WebDriver extends SearchContext{

void get(String url);

String getCurrentUrl();

// and so on....
}
```

all the methods which are present above are overridden in `RemoteWebDriver`

Comment: so writing new WebDriver(); is not valid in Java, since we can **NOT** create object of Interface.

Comment: @Prophet : that was the typo, thnx for pointing it out